# How can compilation of C# code be made to require a given language or compiler version?

Tags: c#

How can a C# program detect it is being compiled under a version of C# that does not contain support for the language features used in that program?

The C# compiler will reject the program, and produce some error message, on encountering the features of the language it does not support. This does not address the issue, which is to state that the program is being compiled with too old a version of the C# compiler, or a C# compiler that does not support the required version of C#

Ideally, it would be as simple as

```
#if CS_VERSION < 3
#error CSharp 3 or later is required
#end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you can do that with a C# file, but if you're using MSBuild then the project/solution tools version number can stop it from being built with an older version of MSBuild.

Can you give the exact context of this? One "human" solution rather than a technical one might be to try compiling the code with all the "old" versions, and create a document with: "If you get an error like *this* it probably means you're using the wrong version..."

Another option you might want to consider to make that even simpler is to have a single "required features" file. This would be unused by your main app, but ask users to compile that first. If it works, the rest of your build should work. If it doesn't, it's due to using the wrong version. That's likely to produce a smaller range of errors from different versions (in particular it doesn't have the problem that the compiler could list errors from different files in a random order).

Comment: The context of this is compilation of machine generated C# code, via command line compilers, broke with a variety of errors because the older C# compiler (.NET 2005) was picked up on the path before the current version (.NET 2008), and it wasn't immediately obvious the bug was not in the generator of the C# code.

Comment: Okay - are those compilers being run in some sort of script? If so, that's where the RequiredFeatures.cs file would be useful.

Comment: Can you highlight the 4.0 specific feature you are referring to? How is this different to /langVersion? I'd be interested to see what it does with the example I gave below...

Comment: Marc: You're right, it's langversion and it's existed for a while. I was remembering the problems I had before with it, as listed here: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2007/11/20/vs2005-and-vs2008-co-existence.aspx  I've edited the answer to remove that bit - you've got it covered better :)

Answer (score 3):

According to [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha(vs.71).aspx) of preprocessor directives, it doesn't seem possible. We usually can tell by using generics (detects 2.0), using auto properties (3.0) or dynamic (4.0)

Answer (score 2):

There is no predefined symbol for this; you could create your own symbols and define them in your build script. Note that you can fix the language version at the project level:

Project properties -> Build -> Advanced -> Language Version:

- ISO-1 is C# 1.2
- ISO-2 is C# 2.0

(maps to the `csc /langversion` parameter)

But note that this doesn't cover everything - there are a few things that this will let through - particularly in the area of generic type inference. This is only an issue if you need to support old compilers; in which case... **test** with an old compiler.

For example:

```
int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
string[] arr2 = Array.ConvertAll(arr1, delegate (int i) {return i.ToString();});
```

This works in .NET 3.5/ISO-2 (pseudo C# 2.0), but doesn't work in .NET 2.0 (proper C# 2.0).

Answer (score 2):

Easy: The compiler will fail and give you an error if it can't compile the code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can read the supportedRuntime element:

Then you can define the directive you want based on the supportedRuntime, using [CSharpProjectConfigurationProperties3.DefineConstants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vslangproj80.csharpprojectconfigurationproperties3.defineconstants.aspx).

You would create a macro in VS to use this.