# How to find what versions of C# and .NET/Mono are being used?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

You can use `System.Environment.Version` to the get the version of the CLR; how do you get the versions of C# and of the .NET or Mono framework currently being used?

EDIT: I am NOT asking how to find whether you are using Mono or .NET. (The very first version of my question did ask that as a secondary question, but I deleted that almost immediately when I saw that question answered elsewhere.) The questions here are (1) how to figure out what version of C# you are working with, and (2) what version of .NET you have (as opposed to the version of the CLR, which [isn't the same thing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx)).

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951856/is-there-an-easy-way-to-check-net-framework-version-using-c)

Comment: At *execution* time, there is no 'C#' being used...

Comment: @AakashM -- ah right, the Python part of my brain was taking over there. Is there any C# preprocessor directive for checking the compiler version number?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955623/how-can-compilation-of-c-sharp-code-be-made-to-require-a-given-language-or-compi) suggests it's not straightforward.

Answer (score 6):

Checking if you're running in mono:

```
public static bool IsRunningOnMono ()
{
    return Type.GetType ("Mono.Runtime") != null;
}
```

Checking the mono version:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime");
if (type != null)
{                                          
    MethodInfo dispalayName = type.GetMethod("GetDisplayName", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static); 
    if (dispalayName != null)                   
        Console.WriteLine(dispalayName.Invoke(null, null)); 
}
```

If you're not in Mono, then you still use `System.Environment.Version`

Comment: Thanks. For .NET, `System.Environment.Version` is for the CLR version, not the .NET framework version, no?

Answer (score 0):

a very similar question has been asked already:

```
public static bool IsRunningOnMono ()
{
    return Type.GetType ("Mono.Runtime") != null;
}
```

[How to detect which .NET runtime is being used (MS vs. Mono)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721161/how-to-detect-which-net-runtime-is-being-used-ms-vs-mono)

and for detecting the .NET framework's version currently used at runtime for execution you can check `Environment.Version`

Comment: `Environment.Version` is for the CLR version, not the .NET framework version, no?